# Columna generada en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, como puedo hacer para poner una condición sobre una columna generada, me explico con este ejercicio que estoy realizando:

Liste los clientes activos que hayan alquilado más de 5 películas distintas en el último año y que se encuentren desincorporadas. La salida debe mostrar : NroCliente, NombreC, Apellidos, TotalPeliculasAlquiladas, ordenados por TotalPeliculasAquiladas en forma descendente.

Esto es lo que llevo hecho:

```
SELECT NumCliente, NombreC, 
       (SELECT count(pr.numcliente) FROM prestamos pr
        WHERE cl.numcliente = pr.numcliente 
              AND pr.fechaprestamo BETWEEN '2018-12-31' AND '2020-01-01') as TotalPeliculasAlquiladas
FROM clientes cl, peliculas pe
WHERE (cl.estatusc = 'Activo' AND TotalPeliculasAlquiladas > 5 AND pe.fechadesincorporacion < CURRENT_DATE)
ORDER BY (TotalPeliculasAlquiladas) DESC
```

Llevo horas tratando de resolverlo, pero siempre me tira el mismo error:

```
ERROR:  no existe la columna «totalpeliculasalquiladas»
LINE 6: WHERE (estatusc = 'Activo' AND TotalPeliculasAlquiladas > 5...
                                       ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 261
```

Hace como que si no detecta la columna calculada pero al momento de de ordenar por esa columna si la ordena perfectamente, así que no se cual sea el problema

Tampoco logro encontrar una forma de filtrar que las peliculas alquiladas repetidas no se cuenten. Por cierto, estoy usando PostgreSQL.

Sin mas que decir espero que puedan ayudarme a resolver ese error. Un saludo.

Comment: analiza la opción de aplica la clausula `LATERAL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es una subconsulta, como lo indicas en tu respuesta aceptada. Sin embargo, desde 9.x PostgreSQL permite hacer consultas CTE (Common table expressions).

Su estructura es como se muestra en el ejemplo de la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html):

```
WITH regional_sales AS (
        SELECT region, SUM(amount) AS total_sales
        FROM orders
        GROUP BY region
     ), top_regions AS (
        SELECT region
        FROM regional_sales
        WHERE total_sales > (SELECT SUM(total_sales)/10 FROM regional_sales)
     )
SELECT region,
       product,
       SUM(quantity) AS product_units,
       SUM(amount) AS product_sales
FROM orders
WHERE region IN (SELECT region FROM top_regions)
GROUP BY region, product;
```

Así, indicando en el bloque WITH una proyección (que en tu pregunta sería la subconsulta) con un alias, podemos usar campos de ese resultset en nuestro SELECT de toda la vida.

Dependiendo de la versión que uses, habrá optimizaciones sobre el uso de esta estructura. Las CTE, además, son soportadas por diferentes motores (con algunos detallitos en la sintaxis).

Answer (score 0):

Para cualquier interesado estuve investigando y di con que SQL no permite realizar algunas operaciones con columnas con un alias, esto es debido a que el realiza los cálculos de estás columnas después de que todas las demás líneas fueron ejecutadas, una posible solución a esto es la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT NumCliente, NombreC, 
       (SELECT count(pr.numcliente) FROM prestamos pr
        WHERE cl.numcliente = pr.numcliente 
              AND pr.fechaprestamo BETWEEN '2018-12-31' AND '2020-01-01') as TotalPeliculasAlquiladas
FROM clientes cl, peliculas pe
WHERE (cl.estatusc = 'Activo' AND pe.fechadesincorporacion < CURRENT_DATE)
ORDER BY (TotalPeliculasAlquiladas) DESC)
) AS TablaInterna
WHERE Totalpeliculasalquiladas > 5
```

De esta manera nos aseguramos de que ya calcule la columna para así poder manejarla y realizar operaciones sobre ella. Un saludo.